# Need help in understanding objective c code

Tags: objective-c

I need some help in understanding the following code:

1. What is the meaning of '@' in @"Reload"

   button = MakeTestButton(&button_rect, @"Reload", content);
   [button setTarget:web_view];
   [button setAction:@selector(reload:)];
2. Where I can find the definition of "@selector(reload:)"?

Answer (score 5):

1. String constants are declared as `@"some text"` in objective-c. This creates an instance of `NSString`.
2. I recommend you read Apple's [documentation on selectors](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocSelectors.html). Basically, `@selector(reload:)` will get a pointer to the method that will be called when an objects receives a `reload:` message.

Comment: It's more accurate to say @selector(reload:) gives you the *name* of the method. You can get a pointer to a method, but that's quite different and doesn't work the same way.

Answer (score 4):

`@selector` is a built in primitive in the language.  Think of `@selector(reload:)` as “the name of the method `reload:`”.  It returns a `SEL`, which you can then pass to a function and later use it to call the method `reload:`.  In the context of your code, when you click the button, the button will call `[web_view reload:self]`.

In `@"Reload"`, the `@` means that it's an `NSString` instance instead of a `char const *`.

Answer (score 4):

1. The @ sign indicates to the compiler that the string is an NSString instead of a standard "C" string. This is a shortcut for creating NSString objects.
2. See [Explanation of Cocoa @selector usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543161/explanation-of-cocoa-selector-usage)