# Calling a method from another class in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates

I have 2 classes, say class A and class B. 
Class B is created in class A.
I have a method in class A, which needs to be executed in both class A and class B. Calling the method in class A itself is fine. But I am not sure about calling the method in class B. 
I have tried declaring the method as static, but since I can't use instance variables inside the static method, I think using delegates would be a good idea. Since I am from a C# background, I am not sure about using it in Objective C. Conceptually, I have implemented what I need in C# as shown below. Just wanted to know what the equivalent of it would be in Objective C.

```
class A
{

    public A()
    {
        B myclass = new B(() => calculate());                
    }

    public void calculate()
    {
        // todo
    }
}

class B
{
    public B(Action calculate)
    {
        calculate();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this using protocols.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just happened to see this post while researching.  Here is a sample code:

ClassA.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ClassB.h"

@interface ClassA : NSObject <ClassBDelegate>
@end
```

ClassA.m file:

```
#import "ClassA.h"
@implementation ClassA
-(void)createAnInstanceOfClassB
{
    ClassB *myClassB = [[ClassB alloc]init];  //create an instance of ClassB
    myClassB.delegate = self;  //set self as the delegate
//    [myClassB optionalClassBMethod];  //this is optional to your question.  If you also want ClassA to call method from ClassB
}

-(void)calculate
{
    NSLog(@"Do calculate thing!");  // calculate can be called from ClassB or ClassA
}

@end
```

ClassB.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@protocol ClassBDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)calculate;   //method from ClassA
@end

@interface ClassB : NSObject
@property (assign) id <ClassBDelegate> delegate;
//-(void)optionalClassBMethod;   //this is optional to your question.  If you also want ClassA to call method from ClassB
@end
```

ClassB.m file:

```
#import "ClassB.h"
@implementation ClassB
@synthesize delegate;

-(void)whateverMethod
{
    [self.delegate calculate];  // calling method "calculate" on ClassA
}

//-(void)optionalClassBMethod   //this is optional to your question.  If you also want ClassA to call method from ClassB
//{
//    NSLog(@"optionalClassBMethod");
//    [self whateverMethod];
//}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is possible with Objective C.

You can refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297680/how-do-sel-and-selector-work-in-iphone-sdk). But for that you have to learn some syntax of Objective C.

If you are not familiar with Objective C & not direct deal with Cocoa frame work then you can do your work using Objective C++. Where you can write your code in C++.

Here you can use function pointer & pass static method of class A.

Or you can define interface class. Derive class A from that & pass object of A to class B.

Answer (score 0):

You could make one class a delegate of the other but that is kind of arbitrary relationship-wise.

Is there any reason not to use inheritance - both A + B subclass from Z - and Z is where your common method is? Then they could both call `[self calculate];`

Comment: I would prefer using delegates. Want to see how its done in the above case.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using notificationCenter. e.g

Class A
.h

```
@interface A: UIViewController
-(void)classAandBMethod;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation
-(void)willPushToClassB
{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaulCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(classAandBMethod) name:@"classAandBMethod_name" object:nil];
 //push class B
 ClassB *b = [ClassB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassB" ........];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:b animated:YES];
}
@end
```

when you call the method in ClassB:

```
//this method in classB will call the method in Class a.
-(void)callMethodInClassA{
 NSNotification *subject = [NSNotification defaultCenter];
 [subject postNotificationName:@"classAandBMethod_name" object:nil userinfo:whatEverInfoYouWant_dict];
 [subject removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: This is definitely working in my case. But I assume, this is not the way I was looking for.

Comment: Edit: Change `NSNotification` to `NSNotificationCenter` in `(void)callMethodInClassA` in ClassB

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what you are looking for is blocks.

In class A, you can define calculate() as a block.

Then in class B, you could have some kind of method that took in a block for calculation and returned some new instance of B based on the calculation (I'm assuming that is what was intended?).