# Method is not calling from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a "class-A" which contains a method

```
-(void)methodA
{
//Logic
}
```

I have another "Class-B" which is a method

```
-(void)methodB
{
//Logic
}
```

Now i am trying to call methodA from Class B

So what i do

In Class B

Create an object of "Class-A"

```
ClassA *a;

@property(nonatomic,retain)ClassA *a;

@synthesize a;

-(void)methodB
{
[self.a methodA];
}
```

But the method is not called. 
So what am i doing  wrong or any other approach for doing this ?

Comment: You created a _pointer_ to ClassA in ClassB, but did you set it to point to an actual object of type ClassA?

Comment: check answers here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629417/calling-a-method-from-another-class-in-objective-c/9629709#comment12245597_9629709

Comment: you need to allocate the class to send messages to it, maybe you did it, but if this is all the code you're using, you didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//In class A
//classA.h

@interface classA : NSObject
  -(void)methodA;
@end

//classA.m
@implementation classA
-(void)methodA
{
    //Logic
}
@end


//In class B
//classB.h

#import classA.h 
@interface classB : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,retain)classA *a;

@end

//classB.m
@implementation classB

@synthesize a;

-(void)methodB
{
    if(!self.a) self.a = [[classA alloc]init];
    [self.a methodA];
    //Logic
}

@end
```

Comment: +1: though i think it should be if(!self.a) self.a = [[classA alloc]init];