# Use selector with two (or more) parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, selector, uigesturerecognizer

I have read this question:

[Relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297680/creating-a-selector-from-a-method-name-with-parameters?rq=1)

And i still don't really get how to use selectors with number of parameters.

Here is my code:

```
{
...
//add single tap gesture to the view
SEL mySelector = @selector(handleSingleTap:withScroll:);
UIGestureRecognizer* singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:mySelector];
[myView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
...
}
```

and:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer withScroll:(UIScrollView*)scroll {
    ...
}
```

But of course it will not work. the `(UIScrollView*)scroll` is `nil` at run time.

How can i set it to be `(UIScrollView*)scroll` for instance?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Read the overview section of the `UIGestureRecognizer` docs. The selector must be in exactly one of two specific forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector of UIGestureRecognizer works only with 1 argument, the recognizer itself calls your selector with only 1 argument so any other arguments in the method will be nil since there are no more arguments in the calling stack.

Comment: "so any other arguments in the method will be nil" more likely, they will be garbage

Answer (score 0):

What I do is sending a single parameter that is actually an NSDictionary ... so I can send lot of information in a single parameter. GL HF