# iOS unrecognized selector sent to instance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am having problems with trying to get a UIButton to work when the user presses it. I keep getting an error saying: unrecognised selector sent to instance

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClick", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.setTitle("Print", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 14)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

func buttonClick(Sender: UIButton!)
{
    myLabelInfo.text = "Hello"
}
```

For a Swift method such as `func buttonClick(Sender: UIButton)` what is the correct string to pass to `addTarget` method for the selector?  Is it "buttonClick", "buttonClick:", "buttonClickSender:" or something else?

Comment: Nice to know you got an error.  Did it occur to you to actually *quote* the error message??

Comment: @HotLicks To be fair, 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' is a pretty common and easy error to troubleshoot. It's kind of like saying "I got a null reference error", we can pretty much figure out what happened.

Comment: try `"buttonClick:" (extra colon)

Comment: @SiLo - But it's a lot easier to diagnose with the actual message, since it tells you precisely what you did wrong.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're using an invalid method signature for the action. You're supplying `buttonClick`, but the method has an argument, so the signature should be `buttonClick:`

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClick:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

For more information about how to format your selectors, you can refer to the accepted answer in the post linked below. The code used in this post may be Objective-C, but all its lessons can be applied here as well.

[Creating a selector from a method name with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297680/creating-a-selector-from-a-method-name-with-parameters)

And as a side note, this code would also be valid if you used `Selector("buttonClicked:")` as the action, but you don't have to because string literals can be implicitly cast to the Selector type.

Quoting from [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/BuildingCocoaApps.pdf)

> An Objective-C selector is a type that refers to the name of an
>   Objective-C method. In Swift, Objective-C selectors are represented by
>   the Selector structure. You can construct a selector with a string
>   literal, such as let mySelector: Selector = "tappedButton:". Because
>   string literals can be automatically converted to selectors, you can
>   pass a string literal to any method that accepts a selector.

Answer (score 11):

#### Swift < 2.2

In Swift < 2.2 the selector method cannot be `private` (unrecognized selector error).

Prefered (by Apple) notation is the string `"methodWithParam:"` notation.

**Troubleshooting**: if you have troubles with `NSTimer` selector, maybe your class should be a subclass of `NSObject`.

#### Swift >= 2.2

Use the `#selector` notation. Read more here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md

For private methods you can use the `@objc` method modifier, like this: `@objc private func timerTick(timer: NSTimer)`.

**No need for subclassing `NSObject` anymore!**

Answer (score 3):

The notation for Swift > 2.2 would be:

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourClass.yourMethod(_:)))
```

Worked for me so far (Xcode 7.3)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass it an actual `Selector`. Try using this line instead:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonClick:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

You also need the `:` at the end of the selector name because you have 1 argument. This is the same as typical Obj-C selector naming.

Comment: `Selector` implicitly converts from a string literal

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the colon while specifying selector.so the line should be

`button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonClick:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - the solution ended up being prefixing the method I wanted the button to execute on click with `@objc`, to expose it in the Objective-C header file and thereby the Objective-C runtime.

Like:

```
@objc func buttonClick(Sender: UIButton!)
{
    myLabelInfo.text = "Hello"
}
```