# Unrecognized selector sent to instance tableview swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, addtarget

In my `cellFoRowAtIndexPath` I want to add a function on a button that belongs to the cell.

In my `cellFoRowAtIndexPath` I have added this code.

```
cell.acceptBtn.addTarget(self, action: "acceptRequest", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

And then I have this function here.

```
func acceptRequest(sender: UIButton) {
    println("hello"); 
}
```

When I run the project and click the button on that cell I get a

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' unrecognized selector sent to instance

Something to note is I have another button that I used the same exact way called `declineRequest` which works perfectly fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS unrecognized selector sent to instance in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153058/ios-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
cell.acceptBtn.addTarget(self, action: "acceptRequest:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

… noting that it is `"acceptRequest:"` and not `"acceptRequest"`. The latter implies that the function has no parameters.

Comment: thanks ! it solved my issue... what a silly error but you just saved me will accept answer in 10 min when it lets me