# Paypal ios PaymentViewController not working?

Tags: ios, xcode, paypal, bridging-header

I am adding PayPal to my app but the PaymentViewController won't work. I import the following in my bridging header:

```
      #import "PayPalMobile.h"
      #import "PayPalConfiguration.h"
  #import "PayPalPaymentViewController.h"
  @interface ViewController : UIViewController<PayPalPaymentDelegate>
   @end
  #endif /* Header_h */
```

And my paymentviewcontroller is:

```
   let paymentViewController = PayPalPaymentViewController(payment: payment, configuration: payPalConfig, delegate: self)
```

And my error is "MyClass does not conform to protocol PayPalPaymentDelegate"

Comment: Implement the delegate methods which are required for the protocol "PayPalPaymentDelegate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the following methods in your view controller:

// PayPalPaymentDelegate

```
func payPalPaymentDidCancel(paymentViewController: PayPalPaymentViewController) {

  }

  func payPalPaymentViewController(paymentViewController: PayPalPaymentViewController, didCompletePayment completedPayment: PayPalPayment) {



  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved one error, but now I get:   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController payer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdb33824000

Comment: One of your UI element is not associated with function and you are trying to access the UI element... Check your UI elements are properly bound to function calls.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, but how do you mean Bhagyalaxmi Poojary?

Comment: This may help  you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153058/ios-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-in-swift..  If you dont mind, rate up my answer :)