# @IBAction crashes app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have button and method

```
 switchViewButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as? UIButton
    switchViewButton!.frame = CGRectMake(15, 25, 50, 50)
    switchViewButton!.setTitle("sss", forState: .Normal)
    switchViewButton!.addTarget(self, action: "switchViewFunc", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    switchViewButton!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    switchViewButton!.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    topView.addSubview(switchViewButton)


@IBAction func switchViewFunc(sender : AnyObject){
     println("Button was clicked", sender)}
```

This method crashes app with reason "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

I have another button and method just like this, and it's work perfect. If I'm delete `(sender : AnyObject)` it works. I cann't understand what is wrong

Comment: Why are you using an IBAction when you're adding it as a target manually? IBAction is specifically for hooking things in IB. You could just define this as a regular function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add action this way (pay attention to ":"

```
switchViewButton!.addTarget(self, action: "switchViewFunc:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: It's to strange, I have another button with code lockButton!.addTarget(self, action: "lockandUnlock", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) and it's not crashes app

Comment: If you have a parameter in switchViewFunc then you need to add :

Comment: @IvanR Then that function doesn't have any parameters. You need to understand how method signatures work. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297680/creating-a-selector-from-a-method-name-with-parameters

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func switchViewFunc(sender : AnyObject){
     println("Button was clicked", sender)} - ?????
```

Try this:

```
func switchViewFunc(sender : UIButton!){
     println("Button was clicked", sender)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@IBAction and an argument are not needed.

```
func switchViewFunc(){
    println("Button was clicked", sender)
}
```